# Commission with Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I would like to know how much is the commission on a Paypal Express Checkout transaction.

Thanks for helping, TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the PayPal fee?  It depends on your monthly volume and a few other variables, but here's a basic break-down.

- $0 - $3,000 / mo = 2.9% + 30 cents
- $3,001 - $10,000 / mo = 2.5% + 30 cents
- $10,001 - $100,000 / mo = 2.2% + 30 cents
- $100,000+ / mo = Negotiable with PayPal

For more details, see [PayPal's fee page](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees).